# How does a cloud NAS manage to be accessed from the outside of a LAN through an app?

Tags: dns, nas, nat, home-server, sockets

I have a cloud NAS within my home network and I can't figure out how it manages to be accessed from the outside through an app. How does the app always know at what address requests should be sent, when the public address of my router is always changing? And also, how does my router know that requests from the outside should be forwarded to the NAS? Was the NAS able to setup a static NAT configuration on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is, it doesn’t.

The “Cloud NAS” connects to your service provider. The App connects to the service provider. A tunnel is created between the two devices via the service provider.

Or, the device can use uPNP to auto configure port forwarding on your router and some type of dynamic DNS service to handle the changing IP.

Or, a combination of both.

This operation is typically described in the supporting documentation of your device.

Comment: This is known as hole-punching. You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)

Comment: @MarioJost in theory yes. In practice it’s almost non-existent. You’ll notice all references to this type of NAT traversal is from decades old literature. For UDP, it’s a possibility due to the lack of session state. But for TCP, no, it’s not possible. The process is so unreliable it would be a waste of time in any case. You are, in essence, trying to bypass the security features of a firewall. A two decade old firewall might work, but any modern equipment has long made this an impossibility.

Comment: What you refer to, is UDP hole punching which is very basic and does not work for TCP, yes i agree. But there is a TCP hole punching that works great. Only issue here is the port guessing. You can read more about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching
Basically, a server that both parties connect to, tells both sides the public IPs of the other side. Both send TCP SYN connections on certain ports to open up a connection. Whoever is slower, will reach an open connection on the other side and can accomplish a TCP handshake.

Comment: @MarioJost Your claim is from a wiki based on an article from 1981. Let me quote a couple sentences in your wiki: "TCP hole punching is an experimentally used NAT traversal technique"; "It does not work with all types of NATs." Stateful firewalls should reject packets with invalid sequence numbers or packets that are not in the expected state. A SYN packet is expected to be responded to by a SYN/ACK with a sequence number of ISN+1. It most certainly does not "work great" and if it works at all it is because the firewall has a security flaw.